# Tableview in UIView - How to size cell and meaning of shadow

Tags: xcode, storyboard, tableview

I added a tableview to a uiview in Storyboard and am having trouble getting the cell to be the right size.  It is currently unusually large as a result of my trying to resize the tableview to fit the uiview.  Can anyone tell me how to resize the cell (The upper handle is not visible and the dimensions are disabled in size inspector) and also why it the screen has a section in white in the middle...What is the white relative to the grey?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you're putting a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`, if the tableView will be the size of the UIView?  Are you adding another control?  If not, you could simply use a `UITableViewController`, which would automatically be the size of the screen.

Comment: As for the cells, I don't see any, unless you made the one cell so large, its height no longer fits in the visible area.

Comment: The reason I put it in a UIView is to have a button as well as the table.  I could not manage to resize the cell so I deleted everything and started over.  However, I still don't understand what the white area is.

Comment: You could add a button (`UIBarButtonItem`) to a `UITableViewController`'s toolbar.